# Initialization of set with comparator

Tags: c++, set

I have a problem with initialization of set with comparator.

.h file:

```
class Comparator
{
public:
    const std::vector <long long> &dist;
public: 
    Comparator(const std::vector <long long>& _dist): dist(_dist){}
};

class SetComparator: public Heap
{
private:
    std::set <int, Comparator> heap;
public:
    SetComparator();
};
```

Here is constructor:

```
SetComparator::SetComparator()
{
    heap(Comparator(dist));
}
```

When I try to compile it, i have such error:

```
SetComparator.cpp:8:23: error: no match for call to '(std::set<int, Comparator>) (Comparator)'
  heap(Comparator(dist));
```

What should I correct in my code?

Comment: `SetComparator::SetComparator() : heap(Comparator(dist)) {}`, that is, it should be lifted up to mem-initializer-list from the body of your ctor

Answer (score 1):

The only way to initialize a custom comparator of an `std::set` is to specify it in the set's constructor. Non-static data members' constructors calls can be customized on the *mem-initializer-list*:

```
SetComparator::SetComparator() : heap(Comparator(dist)) {}
//                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

or (C++11) by providing a *member-initializer*:

```
class SetComparator: public Heap
{
private:
    std::vector <long long> dist;
    std::set <int, Comparator> heap{ Comparator(dist) }; 
    //                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
public:
    SetComparator();
};
```